# Hardhat Staging test is getting errors

Tags: etherscan, testing, chai

```
const { getNamedAccounts, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")

const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
} = require("../../helper-hardhat-config.js")

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("Lottery", function () {
      let lottery, deployer, lotteryEnterenceFee

      const chainId = network.config.chainId

      beforeEach(async function () {
        console.log(chainId)
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery", deployer)
        lotteryEnterenceFee = await lottery.getEnterenceFee()
      })

      describe("fulfillRandwomWords", function () {
        it("works with live chainlink Keepers and Chainklink VRF, we get a random winner", async function () {
          const startingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()
          const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
          await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!")
            lottery.once("WinnterPicked", async () => {
              try {
                const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner()
                const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                const winnerEndingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                const endgingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()

                await expect(lottery.getPlayer(0)).to.be.reverted
                assert.equal(recentWinner.toString(), accounts[0].toString())
                assert.equal(lotteryState, 0)
                assert.equal(
                  winnerEndingBalance.toString(),
                  winnerStartingBalance.add(lotteryEnterenceFee).toString()
                )

                assert.equal(endgingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                resolve()
              } catch (e) {
                reject(e)
              }
            })
            await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnterenceFee })
            const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

**Error:**
replacement fee too low [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.7.2) {"reason":"replacement fee too low","code":"REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED","error":{"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true},"method":"sendTransaction"} Error: replacement fee too low [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.7.2)
at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
at checkError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:112:16)
at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:265:24
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
reason: 'replacement fee too low',
code: 'REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED',
error: ProviderError: HttpProviderError
at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)
at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5),
method: 'sendTransaction',
transaction: undefined
}
1) "before each" hook for "works with live chainlink Keepers and Chainklink VRF, we get a random winner"

0 passing (5s)
1 failing

1. Lottery
   "before each" hook for "works with live chainlink Keepers and Chainklink VRF, we get a random winner":
   ERROR processing C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:
   Error: replacement fee too low [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.7.2)
   at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
   at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
   at checkError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:112:16)
   at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:265:24
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:
   Error: replacement fee too low [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:83:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=REPLACEMENT_UNDERPRICED, version=providers/5.7.2)
   at Logger.makeError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
   at Logger.throwError (node_modules@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
   at checkError (node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:112:16)
   at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:265:24
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
   at Object.fixture (node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:315:9)
   at Context. (test\stagging\Lottery.stagging.js:19:9)

Can someone help me with this error...